# App crashes when I click on a programmatically created button

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have an old project that uses retain/release/dealloc and I want to use it on another project that uses ARC. I solved all the errors ( I just needed to delete all the retain, release and dealloc from the old project) and the app runs, but when I click on a button programmatically created the app crashes.
The button is declared with the following method:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And the action is  this:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Button action");
}
```

When the app crash I get no errors but if I write X on the compiler I get the following message:

> error: memory read takes a start address expression with an optional
>   end address expression. Expressions should be quoted if they contain
>   spaces or other special characters.

Did I forget to add something to make it work on ARC or deleting all the retain/release/dealloc is wrong?

Comment: well you have two : after action ? Unless this is a typo on here.

Comment: sorry it was just a typing error

Comment: are you adding your button to view?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine until I press the button and the app crashes

Comment: Add the following line after the line where you add the target to the button: `NSLog(@"Responds: %@", [self respondToSelector:@selector(buttonClicked:)] ? @"YES" : @"NO");`. And let us know what is printed in the console log when running the app

Comment: This is the log:

     2014-07-30 12:29:46.443 prova alert[2915:70b] Responds: YES